# memory leaks in golang

Tags: go, memory-leaks

Here is the code.
In the golang main function, which in main.go

```
func main() {
    rgc.GetRgcService()
}
```

where the `rgc` is in another golang file, named `mrgc.go`. The code inside is

```
package rgc
func GetRgcService() (svc *RgcService, err error) {}
```

The function GetRgcService is a empty function.

However, when I used `valgrind` to test the memory, I got the following output

```
 ==58156== HEAP SUMMARY:
 ==58156==     in use at exit: 1,152 bytes in 4 blocks
 ==58156==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 5 frees, 1,304 bytes allocated
 ==58156== 288 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 4 of 4
 ==58156==    at 0x4A27F63: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:593)
 ==58156==    by 0x4010DE1: allocate_dtv (in /home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.bpkg-r2/gcc-4.8.2.bpkg-r2/lib64/ld-2.18.so)
==58156==    by 0x40114ED: _dl_allocate_tls (in /home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.bpkg-r2/gcc-4.8.2.bpkg-r2/lib64/ld-2.18.so)
==58156==    by 0x4B36DE2: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.bpkg-r2/gcc-4.8.2.bpkg-r2/lib64/libpthread-2.18.so)
==58156==    by 0x4B2937: _cgo_sys_thread_start (gcc_linux_amd64.c:75)
==58156==    by 0x45506C: runtime.asmcgocall (/home/map/.jumbo/lib/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:612)
==58156==    by 0x50619F: ??? (in /home/users/zhanghuaizhi/ttt.38)
==58156==    by 0xC7FFFFFFFF: ???
==58156==    by 0xC820067FFF: ???
==58156==    by 0x42D69B: runtime.allocm (/home/map/.jumbo/lib/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1260)
==58156==    by 0x42DD3A: runtime.newm (/home/map/.jumbo/lib/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1510)
==58156==    by 0x42E071: runtime.startm (/home/map/.jumbo/lib/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1583)
==58156== 
==58156== LEAK SUMMARY:
==58156==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==58156==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==58156==      possibly lost: 1,152 bytes in 4 blocks
==58156==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==58156==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

How can I free these memory? Since I need to used this function to do a lot of process. It causes lots of memory leaks, which can not be freed

Comment: Go is memory managed and garbage collected, so there is no way to manually free up memory.  and because of that I'm not sure examining Go apps with valgrind is useful.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer `valgrind` is a powerful memory test tool. You can have a try

Comment: @Wyatt His point is that valgrind is useless on Go programs. It doesn't know how Go manages memory. Go does not use malloc/free (except in a few rare cases where the standard library needs to be used, like here) which is what valgrind overrides to know about memory allocations.

Comment: @Wyatt I've been working with valgrind for over a decade :) You just can't  really use it (and don't need to use it) with Go programs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nothing was leaked. The memory is still reachable and it's quite common to not free things on exit, it just takes unnecessary time and the OS will deal with it anyway.

This is memory allocated to thread local storage to a thread that's still running, so it would be incorrect to free it. A better question would be "how do I stop this thread?", to which an answer is: you don't, the Go runtime deals with it. It is quite common to not stop threads at exit, it just takes unnecessary time and the OS will deal with it anyway.

It has nothing to do with your code and your function call, it's something that Go runtime allocates for itself.

Go is a garbage collected language and using valgrind on it will not tell you much. It will neither detect real memory leaks nor will it understand which memory is still in use.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually run garbage collection:
https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GC

I think that would free up the memory, but as others have said, that memory will get freed eventually when the runtime's scheduled garbage collector runs.